# Какой написать алгоритм чтоб можно было получать данные : id , name , username с этого сайта?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
dict = response.json()

for key in dict:
  for i in range(len(key)):
```

Как мне стоит рассматривать то что я получаю с сайта ? Как словарь словарей ? Не понимаю как пройтись по нему и обработать то что поступает. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, вам не следует использовать имя "dict" для
переменной, ведь это встроенная переменная.
Во вторых, вы должны корректно обработать вывод:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
output = response.json()

for key in output:
    for subkey in output:
        print(subkey)
```

Если мой ответ неверен, то, пожалуйста, уточните,
что именно происходит не так.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так это можно перебрать и сделать с этими данными, что пожелаете:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
result = response.json()


for obj in result:
    for key, item in obj.items():
        if not isinstance(item, dict):
            print(f'{key} -> {item}')
        else:
            print(f'{key} ->')
            for key2, item2 in item.items():
                if not isinstance(item2, dict):
                    print(f'  {key2} -> {item2}')
                else:
                    print(f'  {key2} ->')
                    for key3, item3 in item2.items():
                        print(f'    {key3} -> {item3}')

    print('--'*20)
```